# Share text and image using facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-share

How I can share image with predefined text using facebook SDK

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSString:AnyObject]) {
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as?UIImage else {
    return // No image selected.
}

let photo = Photo(image: image, userGenerated: true)
let content = PhotoShareContent(photos: [photo])
try ShareDialog.show(from: myViewController, content: content)
}
```

Comment: You can't use a "pretext" now. FaceBook changed its policy and it's to the user to text.

Comment: I heard that using facebook sdk you can add predefined text.
Actually I need to share user score on facebook so its not possible ?